# Form file upload

Tags: forms, qooxdoo

I am building some forms in **qooxdoo** and need to add a **file upload** section.

Curious to know if anyone has an **elegant solution** to this before I get hacky with it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure whether you consider it elegant, but there is the [UploadWidget](http://qooxdoo.org/contrib/project#uploadwidget) contrib.